# Rspec : stubbing ActiveStorage download method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub, rails-activestorage

I work on a system that stores cached data on S3 with ActiveStorage before using it for something else. In my spec, I want to stub the download method of this file, and load a specific file for testing purpose.

```
allow(user.cached_data).to receive(:download)
                       .and_return(read_json_file('sample_data.json'))
```

(`read_json_file` is a spec helper that `File.read` then `JSON.parse` a data file.)

I get this error :

```
#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f9304a934d8 @name="cached_data", 
@record=#<User id: 4, name: "Bob", email: "bob@email.com",
created_at: "2019-08-22 09:11:16", updated_at: "2019-08-22 09:11:16">,
@dependent=:purge_later> does not implement: download
```

I don't get it, [the docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files) clearly say that this object is supposed to implement download.

**Edit**

As suggested by [Jignesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936494/jignesh-gohel) and [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680847/stephen-hanson), I tried this :

```
allow(user.cached_data.blob).to receive(:download)
                            .and_return(read_json_file('sample_data.json'))
```

and I got the following error :

```
Module::DelegationError:
       blob delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil
```

`user` is generated by FactoryBot, so I'm currently trying to attach my `cached_data` sample file to that object.

My factory looks like that :

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user
    name { 'Robert' }
    email  { 'robert@email.com' }

    after(:build) do |user|
      user.cached_data.attach(io: File.open("spec/support/sample_data.json"), filename: 'sample.json', content_type: 'application/json')
    end
  end
end
```

But when I add that `after build` block to the factory, I get the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::LockWaitTimeout:
       Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError: Lock wait timeout exceeded
```

Maybe it's another Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Rails [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html) doesn't show any `download` method available for `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` instance.

Comment: This method is on the `blob` class: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html and I thought my `user.cached_data` would return a blob...

Comment: Yes `download` is available on `ActiveStorage::Blob` but in your error the instance being worked is of type `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` i.e `user.cached_data` is returning `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` instance.

Comment: Refer [this](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects) in guides which mentions  'You may also want to attach a fixture file in a model test.' and check the example `@message.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.pdf')`which I guess you could employ for your use by attaching the file in the test instead of stubbing.

Comment: FYI see the source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb#L36) on how you get `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` instance and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/changes/create_one.rb#L18) to see how `blob` is made available to `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` instance. Knowing about how the behaviours are made available can help a lot in implementing stubbing in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out in the comments, `#download` is implemented on the `ActiveStorage::Blob` class, not `ActiveStorage::Attached::One`. You can download the file with the following:

```rb
if user.cached_data.attached?
  user.cached_data.blob.download
end
```

I added the check to ensure `cached_data` is attached because `blob` delegates to the attachment and would fail if not attached.

Here is the [documentation for #download](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-download).